# WCF: How to use client proxy and config files on client?

Tags: wcf, proxy, client, config

I'm trying to create the service manually because it's related to requirements of our application.

I want to host the service to console application. How can I do that?

Once again I have 2 projects:

1) Simple library:

It contains only one file with service contract (interface):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessageManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ConvertToUpper(string text);
}
```

I compile that library and DLL file is created as output.

After that I've used svcutil.exe to manually produce client proxy class (.cs) file and config file (output.config).

2) Console application:

It has reference to library DLL and class that implements service contract:

```
public class MessageManager : IMessageManager
{
    public string ConvertToUpper(string text)
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

It also has 2 files produced by svcutil.exe. I've copied all from output.config file to App.config file of console application. And I wrote the client code as follows:

```
MessageManagerClient client = new MessageManagerClient();
string output = client.ConvertToUpper("aaaa");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Here's how App.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding_IMessageManager" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding_IMessageManager"
          contract="IMessageManager" name="DefaultBinding_IMessageManager_IMessageManager" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So, what address I should specify in this case?

Maybe something's wrong in my approach above?

Any help is more than appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. You add the address as an attribute into the `<endpoint/>` defined under the `<client/>`. For example: `<endpoint address="http://localhost/blah" ...`
2. You are correct SOAP envelope is generated for each request. No "files" exist.

Comment: I've tried it, but get this error: "Could not connect to http://localhost:8080/message. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080." I've turned off Windows firewall. The client is ASP.NET application hosted on IIS on my machine.

Comment: So, that's what I don't know how to set. I have client code and config files generated. And what's next to do? I know how to use WCF service using wizard, but there's no wizard in this case.

Comment: So is the service hosted in your asp.net? If so then where is your client?

Comment: How do I know where is my service hosted? I have 2 projects: library where only interface class is and ASP.NET application as client where I copied files generated by svcutil and implemented the interface from the library project. This is approach from one book and I'm also asking myself how to host the service.

Comment: I don't understand manual approach. Is it correct what I did? I created new library project, added only interface (service contract) there and compiled it. After that I created ASP.NET application, added reference to library DLL, added class that implements service contract, added 2 files generated by svcutil.exe, wrote the client code and ran the ASP.NET application.

Comment: I don't know where's the service and how to host it using this manual approach.

Comment: That is correct way to host the service, however, hosting in IIS is much more complext than hosting in other .net hosting containers such as windows service or console. It may be better idea to host the service in a console and test it there.

Comment: Ok. I suppose the service should be hosted in my ASP.NET application. Is it correct? If so, how to call it from the same client ASP.NET application. I've read somewhere that ASP.NET application and service could use the same port and that's why the error message comes up. I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: I've already tried it in console application, but what's the address in config file in that case? Should all those settings be in app.config in that case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16347/discussion-between-hugh-and-tesicg)