# How to change the expected content type of WSDL client?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have imported an online service which is WSDL.

When calling the service methods I get the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 617 bytes of the response were < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>< SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-...

I believe this means that my client expects the service to return data in UTF-8 encoding, while the service returns it in ISO-8859-1. Is there a way for me to alter the client's expected content type to match the one of the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client is .net you can set it as shown here

This is how you would do it in code

```
wsHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8925516/57883

let me see if I can find an example of setting it in the config file directly.

Ah here it is in the question is a sample

[WCF: How to use client proxy and config files on client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12293833/57883)